# Python Search Paragraphs for Keyword

Tags: python

I'm new to python and can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to extract a single paragraph out of a page of content that contains both of my keywords. My code is instead returning the whole page of content if both keywords are found. Can someone help me identify where I'm going wrong? Appreciate the help!

```
def get_summary():
    answer.delete(1.0, END)
    read = wikipedia.page(keyword_entry.get(), auto_suggest=False, redirect=True)
    readContent = read.content
    y = keyword_entry2.get()
    x = keyword_entry.get()

    page = readContent.split('\n')
    for paragraph in page:
        if x in paragraph and y in paragraph:
            answer.insert(INSERT, paragraph.strip()) ### something wrong with this line
            break
        else:
            answer.insert(INSERT, "combo not found")
            break
```

Comment: why did you change original code ? Now answer doesn't match to your code.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables - maybe you have wrong values and this gives you wrong result.

Comment: `break` in `if` and `else` makes no sense - this way you check only first paragraph. You should skip `else` and after `for` loop check if you inserted value - and if you didn't add then insert `"combo not found"` - or you should use special contruction `for/else` (not `if/else`) which runs `else` if you don't use `break` inside `for`

Comment: did you check what you get in `page`? Maybe `split('\n')` doesn't create paragraphs but single element with full page. Maybe it need different method create paragraph. If it is HTML then you may need `<br>` or parser HTML with `lxml` or `beautifulsoup` and then search paragraph in HTML. You didn't create 'minimal working code' so we can't run it to see what is the real problem.

Comment: I reinstated your code. Please add the missing imports (`requests`? `BeautifulSoup`?) and make this code [MCVE]. Where are the objects `answer` or `wikipedia` defined? etc. Please open a clean Python shell and repaste your code into it, to test it works - currently it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the other methods you are calling are doing exactly, but I think I see one error in the code, which might lead you in the right direction.
The expression `if x and y in paragraph` evaluates `x` as a boolean, which in python is `true` for any non-empty string. I think that what you intended instead was `if x in paragraph and y in paragraph`.

Edit:

The fact that the code above returns the whole page suggests that the entire page (including the two keywords) is part of the first paragraph. If it wasn't, the code would break from the loop and insert `"combo not found"` after checking the first paragraph, because it currently breaks from the loop after the first iteration, inserting either the paragraph or failure. Is it possible that there are either no `\n` characters in the webpage, or that they only appear at the end ?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right about this, thanks for letting me know! Unfortunately my issue still persists, but thanks for getting me in the right direction :D